# Pathing issue to Javascript created image element in a Flask app using js modules

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm working on a flask application where most of the HTML on the page is generated by javascript however I am not able to get images stored in my assets folder to show up. I'm not sure if this is a Flask problem, simple image path problem, or maybe has something to do with me using a JS module pattern.

File Tree:

```
app
 ┣ static
 ┃ ┣ assets
 ┃ ┃ ┣ favicon.ico
 ┃ ┃ ┣ globe.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ icons.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ negative.png
 ┃ ┃ ┣ neutral.png
 ┃ ┃ ┗ positive.png
 ┃ ┣ css
 ┃ ┃ ┗ style.css
 ┃ ┣ js
 ┃ ┃ ┣ modules
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ api.js
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ views.js
 ┃ ┃ ┗ main.js
 ┃ ┗ .DS_Store
 ┣ templates
 ┃ ┣ base.html
 ┃ ┗ index.html
 ┣ .DS_Store
 ┣ __init__.py
 ┣ models.py
 ┣ routes.py
 ┣ secrets.py
 ┣ sentAn.py
 ┗ util.py
```

The image is located in the assets folder, I'm generating the HTML in the views.js file

my JS code

```
export default {
  generateStoryMarkup: (story) => {
    return `
        <li>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class ='story-icon-tray'>
            <p class='story-score story-score-icon'><img src="../../assets/positive.png" alt="">POSITIVE SCORE</p>
```

I receive a "GET /positive.png HTTP/1.1" 404 error when I load the page.

Answer (score 0):

You must use static files like this

change

```
../../assets/positive.png
```

to

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/positive.png') }}
```

consulte https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/

Comment: When you use static files, always work with url_for or order method of flask for convert that in compatible files of flask

Comment: This is not working. I'm not serving the images from flask directly onto the HTML, I am creating the <img> elements and appending them to the DOM in the javascript after a button click. I dont think the javascript recognizes Jinja

Comment: Mmmm ok. So try load js files with this form, and then js does its work

Answer (score 0):

So it was a pathing issue. You cannot use jinja syntax in JS, even if it's apart of a Flask application.

```
  generateStoryMarkup: (story) => {
    return `
        <li>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class ='story-icon-tray'>
            <p class='story-score story-score-icon'> 
               <img src="static/assets/positive.png" alt=""> POSITIVE SCORE</p>
```